# Let $A\in L(X)$ and $\lambda\in\Bbb{C}$. Suppose $(x_n)_1^\infty\in X$ with $||x_n||=1$ and $Ax_n-\lambda x_n\to0$. Prove that $\lambda\in\sigma(A)$

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification

Currently I'm self studying functional analysis, namely spectrum of operators. In the text, the author gives the following exercise:

> **Exercise 1**: Let $A:X\to X$ be a bounded linear operator, $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$, and assume that there is a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\subseteq X$ such that $\|x_n\|=1$ and
> $Ax_n-\lambda x_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$. Prove that $\lambda\in\sigma(A)$.

My question is fairly straightfoward: does the solution below work?

*Proof*. By way of contradiction assume that $\lambda\notin\sigma(A)$. Then by definition the inverse $(A-\lambda I)^{-1}$ exists and is bounded.

By the boundedness of the inverse there exists a real number $C>0$ for which $$\|(A-\lambda I)^{-1}y\|\leq C\|y\|\qquad\forall y\in X.$$
Take $y=(A-\lambda I)x$.

Then we obtain the inequality$$\|(A-\lambda I)^{-1}(A-\lambda I)x\|\leq C\|(A-\lambda I)x\|\qquad \forall x\in X.$$ Hence we get $\dfrac{\|x\|}{C}\leq\|(A-\lambda I)x\|\quad\forall x\in X$.

Since $\|x_n\|=1$, we have $\dfrac{1}{C}\leq\|(A-\lambda I)x_n\|\quad\forall n$.
As such $Ax_n-\lambda x_n\not\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, a contradiction. Therefore indeed $\lambda\in\sigma(A)$.

Comment: What is $X?$ Banach?

Comment: Why is $A-\lambda I$ onto and what does this have to do with $(A-\lambda I)x\in X$?  Did you want inverses on both operators?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Infinite dimensional Banach spaces, I believe! The author doesn't actually say this, but assumes it throughout the chapter, so I'll assume it in the exercise.

Comment: @JasonDeVito: $\lambda\notin\sigma(A)$ means, to my knowledge, that $A-\lambda I$ is invertible and also bounded by the Open Mapping Theorem. Being invertible means one-to-one and onto, hence in particular $A-\lambda I$ is onto. Onto gives us that $\text{Im}(A-\lambda I)=X$ so $\{(A-\lambda I)x:x\in X\}=X$. So for any $x\in X$, $(A-\lambda I)x\in X$.

Comment: the proof is fine. you should change the title - to what I don't know exactly but the present title is too curious

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Thanks! And I agree, I'll edit the title.

Comment: That still seems like a lot of work to prove $(A-\lambda I)x \in X$.  I mean, $A$ has image in $X$ by assumption, so just using the fact that $X$ is a vector space guarantees that $(A-\lambda I)x\in X$.  From your proof,  it seems to me that what you want to conclude is not that $(A-\lambda I)x\in X$, but rather, that every $y\in X$ has this form.

Comment: Note I hadn't read it carefully when I said the proof was fine. There's one spot where you really don't say what you mean/need. Jason is exactly right.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: I see. Does it look correct now?

Comment: much better....